# Azure AD Conditional Access Audit Log?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Looking for any documentation or reference for Azure AD Conditional Access Audit\Sign-In Logs. For example, i'd like to generate a report of all users who have been blocked due to a defined Conditional Access Policy.

It seems that events (such as blocking users through policy) do not appear in the Azure Active Directory Sign-In or Audit logs. Are these events recorded anywhere within OMS \ Azure Reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to Sign-ins logs, you can see a dropdown for Conditional Access where you can check if users are blocked.

Comment: Thanks! At the time of posting that was not available, but looks like they added that functionality in July 2018 => https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2018/07/25/public-preview-for-conditional-access-information-in-azure-ad-sign-ins-report/